# Evaluating integral to obtain marginal PDF related to Tikhonov Regularization

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability, inference, regularization, marginal-distribution

I am attempting to derive the marginal PDF for an application of the Gibbs Sampler. My joint PDF contains:

$P(b,x) = \frac{1}{\sigma^{n}}\exp \left( -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\left\lVert b-Ax\right\rVert^2-\frac{\alpha^2}{2\sigma^2}\left\lVert Lx \right\rVert^2\right)$

Or, as I can obtain a covariance matrix:

$P(b,x) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n}\vert\Sigma\vert^2}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(b-Ax)^{\mathrm{T}}\Sigma(b-Ax) - \frac{\alpha^2}{2} (Lx)^{\mathrm{T}}\Sigma(Lx)\right)$

Where $b$ is an n-by-1 vector representing observed data, $x$ is an m-by-1 vector that is a parameter to be estimated, $A$ is an n-by-m matrix containing the physical model, $L$ is an n-by-m second-derivative operator matrix, and $\alpha$ is a scalar. In my particular case, m=n, and is on the order of 100-500. I wish to marginalize over $x$,

$P(x\vert b) = \frac{P(x,b)}{\int P(x,b) \mathrm{d}x}$

and therefore am attempting to evaluate the integral:

$\frac{1}{\sigma^{n}}\int_0^t\exp \left( -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\left\lVert b-Ax\right\rVert^2-\frac{\alpha^2}{2\sigma^2}\left\lVert Lx \right\rVert^2\right)\mathrm{d}x$

or

$\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n}\vert\Sigma\vert^2}\int_0^t\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(b-Ax)^{\mathrm{T}}\Sigma(b-Ax) - \frac{\alpha^2}{2} (Lx)^{\mathrm{T}}\Sigma(Lx)\right)\mathrm{d}x$

where $t$ is either positive $\infty$ or a scalar determined by the dimension $n$. The vector $x = x(r)$ is itself a PDF of unknown shape that integrates to unity over $r$, so it is non-negative and the maximum value is $\frac{1}{\Delta r}$. Integrating from 0 to $\infty$ is probably more simple, but it may be an approximation in this case. Rewriting the integral as:

$\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n}\vert\Sigma\vert^2}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} b^{\mathrm{T}}\Sigma b\right) \int_0^t \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}x^{\mathrm{T}}(A^{\mathrm{T}}\Sigma A + \alpha^2 L^{\mathrm{T}} \Sigma L)x - b^{\mathrm{T}}\Sigma A x \right)\mathrm{d}x $

I recognize similarity to the [expression given on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#n-dimensional_with_linear_term):

$\int \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} x^{\mathrm{T}}Ax + B^{\mathrm{T}}x\right)\mathrm{d}x = \sqrt{\frac{(2 \pi)^n}{\vert A\vert}}\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}B^{\mathrm{T}}A^{-1}B\right)$.

My issue is that the matrix $(A^{\mathrm{T}}\Sigma A + \alpha^2 L^{\mathrm{T}} \Sigma L)$ is not symmetric positive definite. The $(A^{\mathrm{T}} A + \alpha^2 L^{\mathrm{T}} L)$ is symmetric positive definite. Plugging the result into MatLab for my particular matrices returns either 0 or NaN, depending on the value of n.

I need to obtain the properly normalized conditional PDF, so I need the correct marginal PDF as a normalization constant. Is this the right approach to be taking? What else should I try?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $\Sigma$ is symmetric and positive definite and if the intersection of the null spaces of $A$ and $L$ is $\{ 0 \}$, then $(A^{T} \Sigma A+\alpha^{2}L^{T} \Sigma L$ will be symmetric and positive definite.  If it's numerically singular, this is most likely due to $\Sigma$ itself being nearly singular.

Comment: You do not have to prove that $p(x\vert b) \propto p(x,b)$. It follows from the definition of the conditional density.

Comment: I do need to obtain the properly normalized conditional PDF in order to draw samples a la Gibbs sampler. In other words, I need an equality relation, not a proportionality.